# principled volume connects to volume and the object is invisible

Tags: volumetrics

version is3.1.2
Follow the tutorial, but don't know why the results are completely different
*(:з)∠)*[image]

Comment: In *Material Preview* it will be hardly noticeable if the *Density* is so low, you should see it if you switch to *Render Preview*

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? can you post a URL?  Also, what do the results you want look like?